# Where can I find good RIM API classes for integration in my blackberry projects?

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-jde

I am new to BB development and it seems a lot of the classes need a lot of work to be able to compete with Android & IPhone classes.  The functionality given by iPhone & Android in terms of field classes seems highly advanced. Is there a place where one can find similarly advanced UI code for BB apps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Which classes exactly?

For UI maybe [Advanced buttons, fields and managers](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/Implement-advanced-buttons-fields-and-managers/ta-p/488276) can help.